# How do you invoke a method from the same class?

Tags: java, bluej

I'm making a dice game for a class and I have no idea how to invoke the dice roll method.

```
public class PigGame{

  public GVdie die1;
  public GVdie die2;
  public int PlayerScore;
  public int ComputerScore;
  public int RoundScore;
  public int winningScore;
  public int Roll1;

  public PigGame(){
    die1 = new GVdie();
    die2 = new GVdie();
    PlayerScore = (0);
    ComputerScore = (0);
    RoundScore = (0);
    winningScore = (100);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig");    
  }

  public int getRoundScore (){
    return RoundScore;   
  }

  public int getPlayerScore (){
    return PlayerScore;
  }

  public int getComputerScore(){
    return ComputerScore;
  }

  public boolean playerWon(){
    if (PlayerScore >= 100)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
  }

  public boolean computerWon(){
    if (ComputerScore >= 100)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
  }

  private void rollDice (){
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();    
    int roll1 = die1.getValue();
    int roll2 = die2.getValue();
    if ((roll1 == 1) || (roll2 == 1))
    RoundScore = 0;
    else
    RoundScore = roll1 + roll2;      

    System.out.println(die1 + "+" + die2 + "=" + (RoundScore));

  }

  public void playerRolls(){
    Roll1.rollDice();

    System.out.print(PlayerScore);
    if(PlayerScore >= 100)
    System.out.println("You have won the game of Pig!");

  }
```

Inside of my public void playerRolls() I need to invoke the rollDice method, and I've been having a really hard time figuring out how to do that. Everything I've done has come up with a new error. That first line of code in that line is clearly wrong, just the last thing I put in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the rollDice() directly in `playerRolls()`. just `rollDice();`. What you are doing now is trying to call the method from an int which is weird. **A private method can be called inside, and only inside, its own class instance**.

```
public void playerRolls(){
   rollDice(); //HERE

   System.out.print(PlayerScore);
   if(PlayerScore >= 100)
       System.out.println("You have won the game of Pig!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped so much. I knew it was going to be stupidly easy fix. I still have a lot more on this project to go hopefully I can finish it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do by `Roll1.rollDice()` is calling a method `rollDice()` of the class int (which I strongly assume is not present).

You can simply call `this.rollDice()` or even just `rollDice()` from within the same class.

`this` is a pointer to the object that you're within at that point.